# Broadcast Receiver for day change

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, receiver

Im trying to use a broadcast receiver in android to execute some code when day change.

Here's my code, but cant get it working

```
static {
    s_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
}


private final BroadcastReceiver m_timeChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
                action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED))
        {
            System.out.println("Broadcast Activated");
        }
    }
};
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the receiver? According to the documentation ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html ) you need to either register it by calling  Context.registerReceiver() or statically publish an implementation through the  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Yeah i did, forgot to put it :
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  registerReceiver(m_timeChangedReceiver, s_intentFilter);

Comment: Did you register for the intents in the manifest? <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"></action>
</intent-filter>

Comment: Also remember that those actions are only triggered, when user manually changes the time settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) instead and schedule a BroadCast intent for the next day at midnight. Declare the BroadcastReceiver that you use as target for the PendingIntent in your Manifest.

Note: alarms are lost when the device is shut down so you should check the date after reboot and reprogram an Alarm if required.